# Parallel.ForEach is not working as expected C#

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I am replacing ForEach to Parallel.ForEach. ForEach is working fine and gives result as expected where as Parallel.ForEach is giving unexpected result.

```
            string[] ids= { };
            string input="AA;AA;111;T#BB;BB;222;T#CC;CC;333;F";
            string typeId, type, value;
            typeId= type=value=string.Empty;
            bool isValid = false;
            if (input.Contains("#"))
            { ids = input.Split('#'); }
            else
            { ids = new string[] { input };}

//using ForEach ,it's working fine,datas are inserted in DB table properly.
            foreach (var id in ids)
            {
                if (id.Contains(";"))
                {
                    var IdInfo = id.Split(';');
                    if (IdInfo[0] != null)
                    {
                        typeId = Info[0];
                    }

                    if (IdInfo.Length >= 2)
                    { type = IdInfo[1]; }

                    if (IdInfo.Length >= 3)
                    { value = IdInfo[2]; }

                    if (IdInfo.Length >= 4)
                    { isValid = IdInfo[3]=="T" ? true:false; } // T=true
                }
                else
                {
                    return;
                }
                DBInsertMethod("someuniqueId", typeId, type, value, isValid);
            }
```

I have replaced same piece of code with Parrallel.ForEach

```
Parallel.ForEach ( ids,(id)=>
            {
                if (id.Contains(";"))
                {
                    var IdInfo = id.Split(';');
                    if (IdInfo[0] != null)
                    {
                        typeId = Info[0];
                    }

                    if (IdInfo.Length >= 2)
                    { type = IdInfo[1]; }

                    if (IdInfo.Length >= 3)
                    { value = IdInfo[2]; }

                    if (IdInfo.Length >= 4)
                    { isValid = IdInfo[3]=="T" ? true:false; } // T=true
                }
                else
                {
                    return;
                }
                DBInsertMethod("someuniqueId", typeId, type, value, isValid);
            });
```

Now same row is inserted three times in table.Any suggestion/advise is appreciated.

Comment: sidenote: `isValid = IdInfo[3]=="T" ? true:false;` can be written as `isValid = IdInfo[3]=="T";`

Comment: Multithreading is an advanced concept you should understand in detail, or simply avoid if it is not needed. Look into threading/locking/concurrency you can read [this chapter](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx) from a great c# book for free online.

Comment: try to declare `typeId`, `type`, `value`, `isValid` inside the `Parallel.Foreach`

Comment: it works, thanks @rmbq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually even if Paralle.Foreach created multiple threads to handle parallel processing, some variables are declared outside of it scope and thus they are unique.
Try to declare them inside the lambda:

```
        Parallel.ForEach ( ids,(id)=>
        {
            string typeId, type, value;
            typeId= type=value=string.Empty;
            bool isValid=false;

            if (id.Contains(";"))
            {
                var IdInfo = id.Split(';');
                if (IdInfo[0] != null)
                {
                    typeId = Info[0];
                }

                if (IdInfo.Length >= 2)
                { type = IdInfo[1]; }

                if (IdInfo.Length >= 3)
                { value = IdInfo[2]; }

                if (IdInfo.Length >= 4)
                { isValid = IdInfo[3]=="T"; } // T=true
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
            DBInsertMethod("someuniqueId", typeId, type, value, isValid);
        });
```

Answer (score 7):

So you have these variables:

```
string typeId, type, value;
bool isValid;
```

If I run this foreach, at any one time typeId is being accessed once.

```
foreach (var item in list)
{
    typeId = item.id;
}
```

Now if I make it parallel, at any one time typeId is being accessed by N threads. N threads that can update it at *any* time.

```
Parallel.ForEach(list, item =>
{
    typeId = item.id;
});
```

Move your temporary variables into the ForEach so that they're scoped to the anonymous function:

```
Parallel.ForEach(list, item =>
{
    string typeId, type, value;
    bool isValid;
    typeId = item.id;
});
```